# Is there a way to list open transactions on SQL Server 2000 database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2000

Does anyone know of any way to list open transactions on SQL Server 2000 database?

I am aware that I can query the view `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions` on SQL 2005 (and later) database versions, however this is not available on SQL 2000.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

For all databases query sys.sysprocesses

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran = 1
```

For the current database use:

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

Answer (score 59):

You can get all the information of active transaction by the help of below query

```
SELECT
trans.session_id AS [SESSION ID],
ESes.host_name AS [HOST NAME],login_name AS [Login NAME],
trans.transaction_id AS [TRANSACTION ID],
tas.name AS [TRANSACTION NAME],tas.transaction_begin_time AS [TRANSACTION 
BEGIN TIME],
tds.database_id AS [DATABASE ID],DBs.name AS [DATABASE NAME]
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions tas
JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions trans
ON (trans.transaction_id=tas.transaction_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_tran_database_transactions tds
ON (tas.transaction_id = tds.transaction_id )
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.databases AS DBs
ON tds.database_id = DBs.database_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions AS ESes
ON trans.session_id = ESes.session_id
WHERE ESes.session_id IS NOT NULL
```

and it will give below similar result [image]

and you close that transaction by the help below **KILL** query by refering session id

```
KILL 77
```

Comment: Wow, this one is very nice, i like the amount of data provided, the only con is that you need to be administrator in order to run it, DBCC OPENTRAN needs fewer permissions. But still... very good

Comment: Very useful, thank you! If it answered the OP's question (SQL 2000), it should have been the accepted answer. Have an upvote...

Answer (score 31):

**DBCC OPENTRAN** helps to identify active transactions that may be preventing log truncation. DBCC OPENTRAN displays information about the oldest active transaction and the oldest distributed and nondistributed replicated transactions, if any, within the transaction log of the specified database. Results are displayed only if there is an active transaction that exists in the log or if the database contains replication information.

An informational message is displayed if there are no active transactions in the log.

[DBCC OPENTRAN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182792.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use this because whenever transaction open more than one transaction then below will work

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses WHERE open_tran <> 0
```

Comment: What is the context on "open more than one transaction"? Can you elaborate on that, for it is unclear what is being presented and the why it is needed.